Recursive search using awk but with pattern input from a file
How to modify this Script recursive search using awk script to replace  by a file with lines of patterns to search?
For example.
find . -type f -exec awk '/FILE_WITH_LINES_TO_SEARCH.txt/{print FILENAME ":\t" $0;}' '{}' \;
Thank you for any hints.
+++++++++ EDITED ++++++++++++++
The initial script works relatively well if you add the search pattern by hand in the script itself, but obviously it is for one search only. It also has the peculiarity that it also searches and adds the matches from the file FILE_WITH_LINES_TO_SEARCH.txt and it is annoying.
The idea is to search in a directory and in its subdirs all the files (all are txt files) for the existing patterns in a file (patterns.txt).
These patterns words, one for each line.
The expected output is to display on screen, or redirect it, all the lines that match each of the matches and discard the rest.
Even, if feasible, that it can be executed in a bash shell script
patterns.txt example.

hello
oneword
twoword
tomorrow
past

...


Expected output.

file.txt : oneword
./path/file1.txt : hello
./path/file2.txt : tomorrow
...


I thank you for your answers, but this is not expected: some of them redo the search and display the whole content of the files in an endless loop.
++++++++++ EDITED  2 ++++++++++++++++
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r awk -f find.awk patterns.txt 

I'm sorry, but the only thing I get is to scroll through absolutely all the contents of the existing files in the directory. It would be even more efficient to do so by adding the pattern each time.
find . -type f -exec awk '/<PATTERN>/{print FILENAME ":\t" $0;}' '{}' \;

Never mind, I don't know awk, so I'll have to look for another alternative to do what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway.

Given that you just want to print each matching line, prefixed by the filename and tab, it might be easier to use grep instead. find . -type f -exec grep -H -T -f FILE_WITH_LINES_TO_SEARCH.txt '{}' \; That does differ in one way though: it prints the (relative) path to each file, not just the filename by itself. For a recursive search, where you potentially have multiple files with the same name but different contents, you probably want that though. If you really don't, it would be pretty easy to use sed (or awk, if you prefer) to get rid of the other parts of the path.

If you really want to use find + awk (eg, your real implementation does more than just print the filename + line), you can use the standard approach of feeding patterns.txt as the first file to awk followed by the file(s) to be processed.
Setup:
mkdir -p testd/path
touch testd/path/file{1..2}.txt

printf "a oneword b\nmore stuff\n"  > testd/file.txt
printf "a hello b\nmore stuff\n"    > testd/path/file1.txt
printf "a tomorrow b\nmore stuff\n" > testd/path/file2.txt

One awk idea:
$ cat find.awk
BEGIN   { OFS = " : " }
FNR==NR { ptn[$0]; next }                  # first file (patterns.txt)
        { for (i in ptn)                   # subsequent file(s)
              if ($0 ~ i) {
                 print FILENAME,$0
                 next
              }
        }

NOTE: while you don't have to place the awk script in a file it does make the find / awk call a bit easier to manage
Our directory/file structure:
$ tree
├── find.awk
├── patterns.txt
├── testd
│   ├── file.txt
│   └── path
│       ├── file1.txt
│       ├── file2.txt

Combiningfind and awk:
find testd -type f -exec awk -f find.awk patterns.txt '{}' \;

This generates:
testd/file.txt : a oneword b
testd/path/file1.txt : a hello b
testd/path/file2.txt : a tomorrow b

While probably not much of a performance issue in this case, keep in mind this will invoke a new awk session for each file.  In this case we're effectively running:
awk -f patterns.awk testd/file.txt
awk -f patterns.awk testd/path/file1.txt
awk -f patterns.awk testd/path/file2.txt

Pulling xargs into the mix can allow us to feed multiple files to a single awk invocation, eg:
find testd -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r awk -f find.awk patterns.txt

This is equivalent to running:
awk -f patterns.awk testd/file.txt testd/path/file1.txt testd/path/file2.txt

This generates:
testd/file.txt : a oneword b
testd/path/file1.txt : a hello b
testd/path/file2.txt : a tomorrow b

NOTE: if for some reason the find | xargs / awk generates an error re: 'too many arguments' then you can limit the number of files fed to awk via xargs -0 -r -n<some_smaller_number> awk -f find.awk patterns.txt

grep might be quicker, but this works too:
cat FILE_WITH_LINES_TO_SEARCH.txt | while read line
do
        find . -type f -exec awk '/'$line'/{print FILENAME ":\t" $0;}' {} \;
done


Running find repeatedly in a loop is horribly inefficient. You want to run find once and have Awk read the input file itself separately within the find invocation. Perhaps see also Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern? though it is only tangentially related.

Tangentially, avoid the useless use of cat and use read -r; and quote "$line"

Also, regarding '/'$line'/, don't let shell variables expand to become part of the body of an awk script, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script, and always quote your variables unless you need to not quote them, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Thanks for the useful tips on how not to do it.  (I not delete this, because of the useful tips, which might help someone else....)
